# parallel sqlAlchemy sessions

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have two parallel sqlAlchemy sessions, one is performing some operations, How it will reflect in other session

for ex.
we have created a session it's updating some data in the database, and the other API will be hitting and it will create a new session and update in same database, In our first session how they will reflect new session changes.

I am creating one session and then it's not closed and in other API will be hitting a new session will be created and update some data in database, I am trying to get the latest values from database

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)